# POST Method on the UI

Tags: javascript, html, crud

[image: Error]
Above I have a screen shot of my UI and I am trying to do a post method method without changing anything in the back end as you see here there is a mysql error I know that I could go back to my node backend server and change it from their and then change it in the UI but if I want to add more movies in my list that would be too much. So my question is how can I do a post request without changing anything in the back end and only executing it in the front end

```js
$(function(){
$("#showMovies").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $.each(response, function(i, movie) {
     const rowText = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
        $("#movies").append(rowText);
      });
    }
  });
});
$("#movieAdded").click(function(a){
  let mydata = {
    idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
    name:$($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
    thumnail_path:$($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
    description:$($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
    year_released:$($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
    language_released:$($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
  }
  displayMovie(mydata);
       $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
       $("#newForm").toggle();
       a.preventDefault();
});
function displayMovie(data) {
  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
    }
});
}
$.ajax({
   method:"DELETE",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/5",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
    const rowText = "<tr>" +
         "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
       $("#movies").append(rowText);
     });
   }
});

$.ajax({
   method:"PUT",
   url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/6",
   dataType: "json",
   data: {
       idmovielist: 6,
       name: 'Lion King',
       thumanail_path: '"https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/',
       description: 'cartoon',
       year_realeased: '2000',
       language_released: 'english'
   },
   success: function (data) {
     $.each(data, function(i, movie) {
    const rowText = "<tr>" +
         "<td>" + movie.idmovielist + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.name + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.thumbnail_path + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.description + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.year_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + movie.language_released + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"deleteMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Delete</button>" + "</td>" +
         "<td>" + "<button button id = \"editMovie\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#exampleModal\">Edit</button>" + "</td>";
       $("#movies").append(rowText);
     });
   }
});
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
table {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
tbody {
  font-family: inherit;
}
html {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="mycrud.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <title>My Movies</title>
  <header>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
  </header>
<button id = "showMovies" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">All Movies</button>
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
  <thead style="background-color:#ddd;" class="table-borderless">
    <tr>
      <th>idmovielist</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>thumnail_path</th>
      <th>description</th>
      <th>year_released</th>
      <th>language_released</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="movies">
    <button id = "movieAdded" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target=#exampleModal>Add</button>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!--<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>!-->

      <div class="container">
        <form id="newForm">
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="idmovielist" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">idmovielist</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="intNum" placeholder="idmovielist">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="thumnail_path" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">thumnail_path</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="thumnail_path" placeholder="thumnail_path">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="description">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="year_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">year_released</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year_released" placeholder="year_released">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="language_released" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">language_released</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="language_released" placeholder="language_released">
                </div>
            </div>
              <button id = "movieAdded" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
              data-target=#exampleModal>Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I will share my back-end code below

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());


const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Adil@123',
  database: 'movies'

});
mysqlConnection.connect(err=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log('It was not successful \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
  } else {
    console.log('Its a success');
  }
  });
 //  Collecting all the movies from the movielist
  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 // Finding a movie based on the `idmovielist` number
   app.get('/movielist',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err, rows,fields) =>{
    if (!err) {
      res.send(rows);
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });

  // Delting a movie
   app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
  // Inserting a movie
  app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist ?",
   req.body,
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});

// Updating the movie list
app.put('/movielist/:id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET ? WHERE = ? ",
[update],
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});


// localhost:3000
app.listen(3000,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Is your question to dynamically reload your html content based on the response you receive? I am assuming you will want to keep your backend ;)

Comment: @Icepickle yes I want to keep my back end but if I want to keep making a post request I do not want to keep changing my back end every time since it becomes very inconvenient